# How to take backup and restore?

Tags: backup, restore

Each time I install ubuntu 14.04 and I have to update the OS and download a whole bunch of softwares which is very boring to do.
So is there any process that I can backup my ubuntu softwares and updates and restore them after installing again ubuntu (without downloading them)?

Note: I am new to ubuntu. So easy explanation and sample code will be very much helpful for me.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Comment: Also, IMO, you need to test your backup by restoring it. Typically I suggest you test it in a VM.